# A/B software updates system image size

Tags: android, updates, auto-update, ota

Recently I've been researching to try and understand Android OTA software updates and have found some great info on the Android source wiki about both A/B updates and traditional ones:

https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/

Specifically, why is it reported in the Pixel partition sizes table

[image]

that "Pixel's A/B system image is half the original non-A/B system image".

According to this the net size is the same as in A/B a system partition of size 2048 MiB is needed for each partition, and for non-A/B it is 4096 MiB. Are these functionally the same in that there are two sets of system files with one for recovery, or is there something else going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

50% of system image is precompiled odex files (-2048MiB)

- Moved them to B partition
- Copied to /data on first boot
- See BOARD_USES_SYSTEM_OTHER_ODEX BoardConfig option
- Now A/B /system takes same space as non-A/B /system

Comment: Didn't think id every get a reply to this, thanks for the info!